# Converting JSON into Python dict

Tags: python, django, json, dictionary

I've been searching around trying to find an answer to this question, and I can't seem to track it down.  Maybe it's too late in the evening to figure the answer out, so I turn to the excellent readers here.

I have the following bit of JSON data that I am pulling out of a CouchDB record:

```
"{\"description\":\"fdsafsa\",\"order\":\"1\",\"place\":\"22 Plainsman Rd, Mississauga, ON, Canada\",\"lat\":43.5969175,\"lng\":-79.7248744,\"locationDate\":\"03/24/2010\"},{\"description\":\"sadfdsa\",\"order\":\"2\",\"place\":\"50 Dawnridge Trail, Brampton, ON, Canada\",\"lat\":43.7304774,\"lng\":-79.8055435,\"locationDate\":\"03/26/2010\"},"
```

This data is stored inside a Python dict under the key '`locations`' in a dict called '`my_plan`'.  I want to covert this data from CouchDB into a Python dict so I can do the following in a Django template:

```
{% for location in my_plan.locations %}                                                           
<tr>
    <td>{{ location.place }}</td>
    <td>{{ location.locationDate }}</td>
</tr>

{% endfor %}
```

I've found lots of info on converting dicts to JSON, but nothing on going back the other way.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The string you show is not a JSON-coded object (eqv to a Python dict) — more like an array (eqv to a list) without brackets and with a stray extra comma at the end.  So (using [simplejson](http://simplejson.googlecode.com/svn/tags/simplejson-2.1.0/docs/index.html) for version portability — the standard library's `json` in 2.6 is fine too of course!-):

```
>>> import simplejson
>>> js = "{\"description\":\"fdsafsa\",\"order\":\"1\",\"place\":\"22 Plainsman Rd, Mississauga, ON, Canada\",\"lat\":43.5969175,\"lng\":-79.7248744,\"locationDate\":\"03/24/2010\"},{\"description\":\"sadfdsa\",\"order\":\"2\",\"place\":\"50 Dawnridge Trail, Brampton, ON, Canada\",\"lat\":43.7304774,\"lng\":-79.8055435,\"locationDate\":\"03/26/2010\"},"
>>> simplejson.loads('[%s]' % js[:-1])
[{'description': 'fdsafsa', 'order': '1', 'place': '22 Plainsman Rd, Mississauga, ON, Canada', 'lat': 43.596917500000004, 'lng': -79.724874400000004, 'locationDate': '03/24/2010'}, {'description': 'sadfdsa', 'order': '2', 'place': '50 Dawnridge Trail, Brampton, ON, Canada', 'lat': 43.730477399999998, 'lng': -79.805543499999999, 'locationDate': '03/26/2010'}]
```

If you really want a dict you'll have to specify how to treat these two unnamed items, i.e., what arbitrary keys you want to slap on them...?

Comment: Your solution worked perfectly.  Thanks!  I will fix the routine that *generates* that data before it goes into CouchDB to not append that extra comma.  A bit of late-night coding sloppiness

Comment: @Grumpy, sure -- if I were you, I'd also put the brackets around the string in the DB, just to make sure it's valid JSON rather than "somewhat incomplete JSON" that the receiving code must complete.

Comment: I was doing that before, but cannot remember why I *stopped* doing it...late-night coding requires notes from now on I think

Comment: why not using json module? simplejson is legacy which should be deprecated long time ago. Check answer below why :)

Answer (score 39):

- Use the `json` module for loading JSON. (Pre-2.6 use the third party `simplejson` module, which has the same exact API.)

  ```
  >>> import json
  >>> s = '{"foo": 6, "bar": [1, 2, 3]}'
  >>> d = json.loads(s)
  >>> print d
  {u'foo': 6, u'bar': [1, 2, 3]}
  ```
- Your actual data cannot be loaded this way since it's actually two JSON objects separated by a comma and with a trailing comma. You'll need to separate them or otherwise deal with this.

  - Where did you get this string?

Comment: That string is from data being generated by an application I am working on, sort of a location-and-date social app for people planning trips, pub crawls, etc

Answer (score 2):

```
django.utils.simplejson.loads(someJson)
```

Comment: Doesn't convert to a dict.  I did try that ;)

Comment: The actual error it gives is "Extra data: line 1 column 151 - line 1 column 304 (char 151 - 304)"

Comment: @GrumpyCanuck, Look closely. This isn't one object. It's an object then a comma then an object then a comma.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that out when I saw @Alex Martelli's answer

Answer (score 0):

**First** thing **first**.

Here I have stored your **pulled data string** into a variable named **data_str** which has two **dictionaries**.

```
>>> data_str = "{\"description\":\"fdsafsa\",\"order\":\"1\",\"place\":\"22 Plainsman Rd, Mississauga, ON, Canada\",\"lat\":43.5969175,\"lng\":-79.7248744,\"locationDate\":\"03/24/2010\"},{\"description\":\"sadfdsa\",\"order\":\"2\",\"place\":\"50 Dawnridge Trail, Brampton, ON, Canada\",\"lat\":43.7304774,\"lng\":-79.8055435,\"locationDate\":\"03/26/2010\"},"
```

After that I converted it into another string named **data_str2** which is in **list** form and removed extra comma(**,**) from end (as it gives **error** while string data to **python object** conversion).

```
>>> data_str2 = "[" + data_str[0: 1] + data_str[1: len(data_str)-1] + "]"
```

Finally, I converted this **list string** (a list having 2 dictionaries) into original **python list** and stored it in a variable named **data_list**.

```
>>> import json
>>> data_list = json.loads(data_str2) # Now data_list is a list having 2 dictionaries
```

Now let's print our data.

```
>>> print data_list
[{u'description': u'fdsafsa', u'order': u'1', u'place': u'22 Plainsman Rd, Mississauga, ON, Canada', u'lat': 43.5969175, u'lng': -79.7248744, u'locationDate': u'03/24/2010'}, {u'description': u'sadfdsa', u'order': u'2', u'place': u'50 Dawnridge Trail, Brampton, ON, Canada', u'lat': 43.7304774, u'lng': -79.8055435, u'locationDate': u'03/26/2010'}]
>>> 
>>> print type(data_list)
<type 'list'>
>>> 
>>> print data_list[0]
{u'description': u'fdsafsa', u'order': u'1', u'place': u'22 Plainsman Rd, Mississauga, ON, Canada', u'lat': 43.5969175, u'lng': -79.7248744, u'locationDate': u'03/24/2010'}
>>> 
>>> print data_list[1]
{u'description': u'sadfdsa', u'order': u'2', u'place': u'50 Dawnridge Trail, Brampton, ON, Canada', u'lat': 43.7304774, u'lng': -79.8055435, u'locationDate': u'03/26/2010'}
>>>
```

Pass this **data_list** list from views and access it in your **Django template** as follows,

```
{% for data in locations %}
      <tr>
           <td> {{ data.place }} </td>
           <td> {{ data.locationDate }} </td>
      </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

A sample code segment for your views.

```
def locations(request):
    # YOU HAVE TO WRITE YOUR CODE LOGIC HERE TO GET THE LIST, 
    # I AM WRITING IT DIRECTLY
    data_list = [{u'description': u'fdsafsa', u'order': u'1', u'place': u'22 Plainsman Rd, Mississauga, ON, Canada', u'lat': 43.5969175, u'lng': -79.7248744, u'locationDate': u'03/24/2010'}, {u'description': u'sadfdsa', u'order': u'2', u'place': u'50 Dawnridge Trail, Brampton, ON, Canada', u'lat': 43.7304774, u'lng': -79.8055435, u'locationDate': u'03/26/2010'}]
    return render(request, "locations.html", {"locations": data_list})
```

**IT WORKED NICE.**

Now I wanna **explain** that how I reached to **solution**, I think it will be helpful for beginners. Please see the below explained **step by step** procedure or [see here](https://gist.github.com/hygull/6dfa5d7aa58f496e39c6ff702cb71c6b).

```
>>> import json   
>>>
>>> # A simple attempt
>>> s = "{\"description\":\"fdsafsa\"}"
>>> python_dict = json.loads(s)
>>> python_dict
{u'description': u'fdsafsa'}
>>> # Accessing value using key
>>> python_dict["description"]
u'fdsafsa'
>>> 
>>> # It worked, lets test our given string containing 2 dictionaries(in string form) one by one
>>> # Converting 1st JSON string to Dict
>>> s2 = "{\"description\":\"fdsafsa\",\"order\":\"1\",\"place\":\"22 Plainsman Rd, Mississauga, ON, Canada\",\"lat\":43.5969175,\"lng\":-79.7248744,\"locationDate\":\"03/24/2010\"}"
>>> python_dict2 = json.loads(s2)                                                                                      >>> python_dict2
{u'description': u'fdsafsa', u'order': u'1', u'place': u'22 Plainsman Rd, Mississauga, ON, Canada', u'lat': 43.5969175, u'lng': -79.7248744, u'locationDate': u'03/24/2010'}
>>> 
>>> # Converting 2nd JSON string to Dict
>>> # remove comma(,) from end otherwise you will get the following error
>>> s3 = "{\"description\":\"sadfdsa\",\"order\":\"2\",\"place\":\"50 Dawnridge Trail, Brampton, ON, Canada\",\"lat\":43.7304774,\"lng\":-79.8055435,\"locationDate\":\"03/26/2010\"},"
>>> python_dict3 = json.loads(s3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 339, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 367, in decode
    raise ValueError(errmsg("Extra data", s, end, len(s)))
ValueError: Extra data: line 1 column 152 - line 1 column 153 (char 151 - 152)
>>> 
>>> # Now I removed comma(,) from end and retried, it worked
>>> s3 = "{\"description\":\"sadfdsa\",\"order\":\"2\",\"place\":\"50 Dawnridge Trail, Brampton, ON, Canada\",\"lat\":43.7304774,\"lng\":-79.8055435,\"locationDate\":\"03/26/2010\"}"
>>> python_dict3 = json.loads(s3) 
>>> 
>>> # So now we knew that we have not to include any extra comma at end in the string form of JSON
>>> # For example (Correct form)
>>> details_str = "{\"name\":\"Rishikesh Agrawani\", \"age\": 25}" 
>>> details_dict = json.loads(details_str)
>>> details_dict["name"]
u'Rishikesh Agrawani'
>>> details_dict["age"]
25
>>> # Now (Incorrect form), here comma(,) is at end, just after } 
>>> details_str = "{\"name\":\"Rishikesh Agrawani\", \"age\": 25},"
>>> details_dict = json.loads(details_str)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 339, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 367, in decode
    raise ValueError(errmsg("Extra data", s, end, len(s)))
ValueError: Extra data: line 1 column 41 - line 1 column 42 (char 40 - 41)
>>> 
>>> # The problem is the string does not denote any single python object 
>>> # So we will convert the string into a list form by appending [ at beginning and ] at end
>>> # Now our string will denote a single Python object that is list of 2 dictioanaries
>>> # Lets do this, here I am storing the given string into variable s4
>>> data_str = "{\"description\":\"fdsafsa\",\"order\":\"1\",\"place\":\"22 Plainsman Rd, Mississauga, ON, Canada\",\"lat\":43.5969175,\"lng\":-79.7248744,\"locationDate\":\"03/24/2010\"},{\"description\":\"sadfdsa\",\"order\":\"2\",\"place\":\"50 Dawnridge Trail, Brampton, ON, Canada\",\"lat\":43.7304774,\"lng\":-79.8055435,\"locationDate\":\"03/26/2010\"},"
>>> s5 = "[" + s4[0:1] + s4[1: len(s4)-1] + "]"
>>> s5
'[{"description":"fdsafsa","order":"1","place":"22 Plainsman Rd, Mississauga, ON, Canada","lat":43.5969175,"lng":-79.7248744,"locationDate":"03/24/2010"},{"description":"sadfdsa","order":"2","place":"50 Dawnridge Trail, Brampton, ON, Canada","lat":43.7304774,"lng":-79.8055435,"locationDate":"03/26/2010"}]'
>>> # l is a list of 2 dictionaries
>>> l = json.loads(s5)
>>> l[0]
{u'description': u'fdsafsa', u'order': u'1', u'place': u'22 Plainsman Rd, Mississauga, ON, Canada', u'lat': 43.5969175, u'lng': -79.7248744, u'locationDate': u'03/24/2010'}
>>> 
>>> l[1]
{u'description': u'sadfdsa', u'order': u'2', u'place': u'50 Dawnridge Trail, Brampton, ON, Canada', u'lat': 43.7304774, u'lng': -79.8055435, u'locationDate': u'03/26/2010'}
>>>
```

***Thanks***.

Answer (score 0):

```
Hello here my example
import json
class SimpleObject(object):
    def __init__(self, _dict):
        self.__dict__.update(_dict)

data=json.loads("{\"name\":\"Rishikesh Agrawani\", \"age\": 25}" )  
so=SimpleObject(data)
print (so.name)
print (so.age)

if you transform your data to objects is better and more fast work.
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a combination of other answers:

```
import json
yourString = "{\"description\":\"fdsafsa\",\"order\":\"1\",\"place\":\"22 Plainsman Rd, Mississauga, ON, Canada\",\"lat\":43.5969175,\"lng\":-79.7248744,\"locationDate\":\"03/24/2010\"},{\"description\":\"sadfdsa\",\"order\":\"2\",\"place\":\"50 Dawnridge Trail, Brampton, ON, Canada\",\"lat\":43.7304774,\"lng\":-79.8055435,\"locationDate\":\"03/26/2010\"},"
target = json.loads("[" + yourString[:-1] + "]")
```

outputs

```
[{u'description': u'fdsafsa', u'order': u'1', u'place': u'22 Plainsman Rd, Mississauga, ON, Canada', u'lat': 43.5969175, u'lng': -79.7248744, u'locationDate': u'03/24/2010'}, {u'description': u'sadfdsa', u'order': u'2', u'place': u'50 Dawnridge Trail, Brampton, ON, Canada', u'lat': 43.7304774, u'lng': -79.8055435, u'locationDate': u'03/26/2010'}]
```

As mentioned

- this string contains two json objects, so put it inside an array (the `[]`)
- it has a trailing `,`, remove via `[:-1]` slicing syntax