# How can I convert a JSON dictionary to a python dictionary?

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, web-scraping

I have a JSON file that only contains a JSON dictionary (example: http://www.collegeswimming.com/results/17172/event/4/). Is there any module in Python that will easily convert this into an object I can work with in Python?

Comment: That’s called JSON, by the way. It’s not JavaScript. Fittingly, the module is called `json`.

Comment: json modules is in the standard lib.  http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html

Comment: whoops that's embarrassing...I'll edit that and fix that. and thanks!

Comment: Well, JSON does stand for "JavaScript Object Notation", and the point is that a JSON object is always valid (`eval`-able) source for a JavaScript object (but the reverse is not always true). Of course many people think that was a mistake, given all the security holes and other bugs caused by people using `eval` to parse JSON, or generating data that aren't JSON but still work with JS code, etc., but still, it's a bit misleading to say that it isn't a JavaScript object…

Answer (score 5):

Python's JSON parser http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html

```
>>> import json
>>> json.loads('["foo", {"bar":["baz", null, 1.0, 2]}]')
[u'foo', {u'bar': [u'baz', None, 1.0, 2]}]
>>> json.loads('"\\"foo\\bar"')
u'"foo\x08ar'
>>> from StringIO import StringIO
>>> io = StringIO('["streaming API"]')
>>> json.load(io)
[u'streaming API']
```

Answer (score 5):

That’s called JSON, by the way. It’s not JavaScript. Fittingly, the module is called `json`.

Try [`json.loads`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/json#json.loads)!

Comment: You beat me to the punch. I was going to throw this out there for correction purposes: *http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2485817/converting-json-into-python-dict* Note that there are many questions/answers for this already up on this site and many more.