# Convert redis hash to python dict?

Tags: python, string, redis, hash

Suppose I have a python dict `aa = {"name": "nilesh", "age":29}`
When I store it in redis hash, all datatypes changes to string.

```
import redis
r = redis.StrictRedis()
r.hmset("nilesh_123", aa)
bb = r.hgetall("nilesh_123")
```

Now bb comes as `{'age': '29', 'name': 'nilesh'}`. Is is there any pythonic way to convert this hash returned value to python dict format again ? One way which I see is to store all the datatypes of dictionary values somewhere and then convert them again when I get that hash by iterating the redis hash value, but I am looking for better pythonic solution.

I can store the dict as pickled object in a redis string and then get it and loads it again  using pickle, but I am more interested in using hashes compare to strings.

Answer (score -1):

```
 {'age': '29', 'name': 'nilesh'}
```

is JSON format, try to look for tools that can convert JSON to python dict like:

[Converting JSON into Python dict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2485817/converting-json-into-python-dict)

Comment: python dict is also a json ...!! I want to change the converted string datatypes of values to there older datatypes..

Comment: @NIleshSharma *python dict is also a json* - no it's not, but it's convertible to JSON.

Comment: @vaultah agree, but python is convertible to JSON, but that's not I am asking here

Comment: The string shown here isn't JSON, because the strings are enclosed in single-quotes.

Answer (score -1):

Well, i wouldn't say pythonic way but

```
mydict = eval("{'age': '29', 'name': 'nilesh'}")
```

or (slightly) better [ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html) yet, some say [eval is evil](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html)

Comment: eval("{'age': '29', 'name': 'nilesh'}") returns {'age': '29', 'name': 'nilesh'} , 29 is still is string...which I don't want

Comment: every time you use `eval`, God kills a kitten.