# Python - how to print only keys of list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary, key

I would like to be able my list of dictionaries by key.

However my code is returning the key and the value as follows:

```
for key in products_dicts[0]:
    print(products_dicts[0].keys())
```

Output:

```
dict_keys(['{"uniq_id": "b6c0b6bea69c722939585baeac73c13d", "sku": "pp5006380337", "name_title": "Alfred Dunner\\u00ae Essential Pull On Capri Pant", "description": "You\'ll return to our Alfred Dunner pull-on capris again and again when you want an updated, casual look and all the comfort you love. \\u00a0 elastic waistband approx. 19-21\\" inseam slash pockets polyester washable imported \\u00a0 \\u00a0 \\u00a0", "list_price": "41.09", "sale_price": "24.16", "category": "alfred dunner", "category_tree": "jcpenney|women|alfred dunner", "average_product_rating": 2.625, "product_url": "http://www.jcpenney.com/alfred-dunner-essential-pull-on-capri-pant/prod.jump?ppId=pp5006380337&catId=cat1002110079&&_dyncharset=UTF-8&urlState=/women/shop-brands/alfred-dunner/yellow/_/N-gkmp33Z132/cat.jump", "product_image_urls": "http://s7d9.scene7.com/is/image/JCPenney/DP1228201517142050M.tif?hei=380&amp;wid=380&op_usm=.4,.8,0,0&resmode=sharp2&op_usm=1.5,.8,0,0&resmode=sharp", "brand": "Alfred Dunner", "total_number_reviews": 8, "Reviews": [{"User": "fsdv4141", "Review": "You never have to worry about the fit...Alfred Dunner clothing sizes are true to size and fits perfectly. Great value for the money.", "Score": 2}, {"User": "krpz1113", "Review": "Good quality fabric. Perfect fit. Washed very well no iron.", "Score": 4}, {"User": "mbmg3241", "Review": "I do not normally wear pants or capris that have an elastic waist, but I decided to try these since they were on sale and I loved the color. I was very surprised at how comfortable they are and wear really well even wearing all day. I will buy this style again!", "Score": 4}, {"User": "zeqg1222", "Review": "I love these capris! They fit true to size and are so comfortable to wear. I am planning to order more of them.", "Score": 1}, {"User": "nvfn3212", "Review": "This product is very comfortable and the fabric launders very well", "Score": 1}, {"User": "aajh3423", "Review": "I did not like the fabric. It is 100% polyester I thought it was different.I bought one at the store apprx two monts ago, and I thought it was just like it", "Score": 5}, {"User": "usvp2142", "Review": "What a great deal. Beautiful Pants. Its more than I expected.", "Score": 3}, {"User": "yemw3321", "Review": "Alfred Dunner has great pants, good fit and very comfortable", "Score": 1}], "Bought With": ["898e42fe937a33e8ce5e900ca7a4d924", "8c02c262567a2267cd207e35637feb1c", "b62dd54545cdc1a05d8aaa2d25aed996", "0da4c2dcc8cfa0e71200883b00d22b30", "90c46b841e2eeece992c57071387899c"]}\n'])
```

If I omit the index in my code I get the following error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-c723fc75d649> in <module>
      2 
      3 for key in products_dicts[0]:
----> 4     print(products_dicts.keys())

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

What is strange about that to me is that if I run this code:.

```
print(type(reviewers_dicts[0]))
```

It returns:

```
<class 'dict'>
```

Is this a data structure issue?.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. Do you mean `for key in products_dicts[0]: print(key)`?

Comment: I see a reviewers_dicts and a products_dict in this question. You print one and print the type of the other. How do you populate the one you want to query? Also, the stuff that gets printed looks like you have put a whole string of keys and values into a key of a dictionary

Comment: `<class 'dict'>` is indeed the Dict object, not the keys or values within it

Comment: Yes @Passerby I want to print the dictionary keys

Comment: @doctorlove. Thanks. Please excuse me - I do have two lists of dictionaries, I can assure that the class type of both returns the same. Both were populated using a json.loads operation and then a function to convert them into a list of dictionaries

Comment: @ChristyKail sorry I don't see the relevance of your comment to my question on how to print the keys of dictionaries in a list of dictionaries

Comment: I suspect something has gone wrong with the json_loads, since the first in the for loop seems to be a string with a potential dictionary inside.

Comment: @Passerby your code returns the same as mine: ie the keys but also the first value for each key

Comment: @doctorlove I think you are right. Either it's gone wrong at that stage, or the function to create the list of dictionaries is incorrect.

Comment: Give details of the creation code (either here or as a new question).

Comment: `'{"uniq_id": "b6c0b6bea69c722939585baeac73c13d"...}'` means your key is a very long string that has dictionary like contents. You might need to investigate json loads and watch out for what your string contains. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2485817/converting-json-into-python-dict

Answer (score 1):

Both of your for loops have this format:

```
for item in things:
    print(things.keys())
```

If your `things` are in a list,

```
things[0].keys()
```

will be the `keys` of the first item. To iterate all the items, use the name you choose in the for loop:

```
for item in things:
    print(item.keys())
    #     ^^^^ --- not all things, just the current item
```

Comment: I will try your answer. I will raise a new question with the creation method of the list of dictionaries. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```py
listis = [
    {
        1: "One"
        , 11: "OneOne"
    }
    , {2: "Two"}
    , {3: "Three"}
    , {4: "Four"}
]

for obj in listis:
    for key in obj.keys():
        print(key)
```

You will print all keys of each dictionary in list of dictionaries.

Comment: thanks so much but I do seen to have a data structure issue as your code is returning all keys and values as follows: {"Username": "bkpn1412", "DOB": "31.07.1983", "State": "Oregon", "Reviewed": ["cea76118f6a9110a893de2b7654319c0"]}

{"Username": "eehe1434", "DOB": "08.08.1950", "State": "Idaho", "Reviewed": []}

{"Username": "jjbd1412", "DOB": "26.07.2001", "State": "Georgia", "Reviewed": []}